# WPF, detect which Tab you are navigating AWAY from

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application with multiple tabs.  Under each tab, a user can change some settings (using CheckBoxes, TextBoxes, etc) and then the user must click the "Update" button in order to save those settings.  Everything works fine but one of requirements is to alert the user if he tries to switch to other tab without clicking the "Update" button.
So I'm trying to use the

```
TabItem_LostFocus
```

event handler to achieve it but this event is triggered every time I click on something within the tab.  I guess I can patch this issue by placing

```
e.Handled = true
```

for every control I have but this doesn't sound like an elegant solution (especially when I don't have click event handlers for everything under my tabs).  Is there some other way to determine when you are switching away from the current tab?
Thank you

Comment: do you want to prevent a user from navigation away from the tab if they didn't click OK on your popup?

Comment: I want to prevent the user navigating away from a tab until he saves the changes withing the tab (by clicking the Update button)
  I think I got the answers I was looking for.  But if you have an even more elegant solution, please share :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you just need to data bind to the `TabControl.SelectedIndex` or the `TabControl.SelectedItem` properties:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemCollection}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabItem}" />
```

Then in your view model or code behind:

```
private YourDataType selectedItem;
public YourDataType SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        // selectedItem represents the previous TabItem
        // value represents the new TabItem
        selectedItem = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed!  I'd give you a Vote Up but I don't have credits LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `IsSelected` property of each `TabItem`.. and then do your checking inside the setter

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem IsSelected="{Binding TabItem1IsSelected}"/>
</TabControl>
```

Property:

```
public bool TabItem1IsSelected
{
    get { return _tabItem1IsSelected; }
    set
    {
        if (_tabItem1IsSelected)
        {
            if (!value)
            {
                // Check to see if user has updated

                if (!userUpdated)
                {
                    value = true;
                }
            }
        }

        _tabItem1IsSelected = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a lot simpler than I thought.  I am new to WPF/Binding concept